# Getting last 45 days from today with SQL query

Tags: sql, tableau-api, hana

I’m trying to get a date range from today’s date writing a sql query, today’s date but last 45 days from today so I want the dates in between 45days and today not only the date 45 days ago

Comment: what is your database? , tag it

Comment: why tagged tableau and power-bi?

Comment: I’m getting the data from sap Hana using custom sql in power bi

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To create a **series** of values, e.g. of dates, HANA provides the **[SERIES_GENERATE](https://help.sap.com/viewer/4fe29514fd584807ac9f2a04f6754767/2.0.04/en-US/c8101037ad4344768db31e68e4d30eb4.html)** functions.

For the requirement to create all dates of the past 45 days, one could follow this approach

```
SELECT
   GENERATED_PERIOD_START as DATE_OF_DAY
FROM
   SERIES_GENERATE_DATE('INTERVAL 1 DAY'               
                       , ADD_DAYS(current_date, -45)
                       , current_date);
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use the ADD_DAYS function with a minus value as part of your range, ADD_DAYS(CURRENT_DATE, -45) or e.g. SELECT ADD_DAYS (TO_DATE ('2021-03-03', 'YYYY-MM-DD'), -45) FROM DUMMY

Comment: Thank you for your comment but I’m only getting one date and that the date 45 days ago I’ll like to get the date ranges of the last 45 days

Answer (score 0):

You can use `M_TIME_DIMENSION` table to get dates with other attributes (like month, year, date in ABAP format (dats) etc) with no calculation.

```
select date_sql
from _sys_bi.m_time_dimension
where date_sql between add_days(current_date, -45) and current_date
```